# ¿Por qué no me corre la siguiente sentencia de Oracle SQL? Me sale el error ORA-00907: falta el paréntesis derecho

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Estoy trabajando en la plataforma de APEX Cloud. (APEX 5.0).

```
create table ACCESO
(
   ID_ACCESO            INTEGER              not null,
   ID_VEHICULO          INTEGER,
   ID_ESPACIO           SMALLINT,
   ID_PERSONA           INTEGER,
   VIS_ID_PERSONA       INTEGER,
   FECHA_ENTRADA        DATE,
   FECHA_SALIDA         DATE,
   constraint PK_ACCESO primary key (ID_ACCESO)
   check (
            ((FECHA_ENTRADA IS not null AND FECHA_SALIDA IS null)
            OR
            (FECHA_ENTRADA IS null AND FECHA_SALIDA IS not null))
            AND
            ((ID_PERSONA IS not null AND VIS_ID_PERSONA IS null)
            OR
            (ID_PERSONA IS null AND VIS_ID_PERSONA IS not null))
        )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto (falta una coma despues del PK y poner nombre a la contraint check):

```
create table ACCESO
(
    ID_ACCESO            INTEGER              not null,
    ID_VEHICULO          INTEGER,
    ID_ESPACIO           SMALLINT,
    ID_PERSONA           INTEGER,
    VIS_ID_PERSONA       INTEGER,
    FECHA_ENTRADA        DATE,
    FECHA_SALIDA         DATE,
    constraint PK_ACCESO primary key (ID_ACCESO),
    constraint CK_FECHAS check (
        (
           (FECHA_ENTRADA IS not null AND FECHA_SALIDA IS null)
        OR
           (FECHA_ENTRADA IS null AND FECHA_SALIDA IS not null)
        )
        AND
        (
           (ID_PERSONA IS not null AND VIS_ID_PERSONA IS null)
        OR
           (ID_PERSONA IS null AND VIS_ID_PERSONA IS not null)
        )
    )
);
```